# User Authentication based on if logged in or not django

Tags: django, templates, authentication

I have an issue with my application I'm building. I understand how to validate if a user in django is logged in or not and whether their session is active with:

```
if user is not None and user.is_active:
```

My issue is my django templates specifically with the section with `Register | Login` that look like:

```
                <div id="subnav_registrationLogin">
                    <ul>
                    {% block block_containersupernav %}
                        <li><span><a href="/Register" title="Register for Account">Register</a></span></li>
                        <li style="border:none;"><span><a href="/Login" title="Login To Account">Login</a></span></li>
                    {% endblock block_containersupernav %}
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /subnav_registrationLogin -->
```

The issue is, my template is static and for this little code snippet above needs be more dynamic like:

```
if user is not None and user.is_active:
   Log Out

elif:
   <div id="subnav_registrationLogin">
   <ul>
   {% block block_containersupernav %}
      <li><span><a href="/Register" title="Register for Account">Register</a></span></li>
      <li style="border:none;"><span><a href="/Login" title="Login To Account">Login</a></span></li>
   {% endblock block_containersupernav %}
   </ul>
</div><!-- /subnav_registrationLogin -->
```

How can I achieve this within a template? and if I cannot within a template, how should I be doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that in no way does the `is_active` property tell you if a user is authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are rendered based on the context. So try this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url logout %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <div id="subnav_registrationLogin">
       <ul>
       {% block block_containersupernav %}
          <li><span><a href="/Register" title="Register for Account">Register</a></span></li>
          <li style="border:none;"><span><a href="/Login" title="Login To Account">Login</a></span></li>
       {% endblock block_containersupernav %}
       </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

[`is_authenticated()` is a helper method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) in the `django.contrib.auth.user` model

Also, note that [`is_active` flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) is used to check if the user is active or not, and should be used to check if the user can be successfully logged into the system or not.

You could also access the current logged in user using `request.user.is_authenticated` in the template.

Comment: Works suprisingly well. I also appreciate the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li><a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
<div id="subnav_registrationLogin">
   <ul>
   {% block block_containersupernav %}
      <li><span><a href="/Register" title="Register for Account">Register</a></span></li>
      <li style="border:none;"><span><a href="/Login" title="Login To Account">Login</a></span></li>
   {% endblock block_containersupernav %}
   </ul>
</div><!-- /subnav_registrationLogin -->
{% endif %}
```